# Is Android supports adobe pdf and flash player

Tags: android, pdf

I just wanted to know wether android supports pdf viewer and flash player????please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially Google doesn't provide this softwares but as now in the market most of devices coming with Adobe Reader and Flash Players. Also you can download them via Android Market.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes. Putting the same effort in to my response as you did to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are supported but for Android OS version 2.2 and above for [FP](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer) and 2.1 for [Reader](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.reader&feature=search_result). You can download from MarketPlace.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.reader&feature=search_result

Answer (score 0):

Android Markeplace has the answer:

As of this writing: [79 PDF viewers.](https://market.android.com/search?q=pdf+viewer&c=apps)

And [here's](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer&feature=search_result) the flash player from Adobe.